# Проект в IDEA ищет библиотеку Groovy

Tags: intellij-idea

Пишу на Java. Вот собственно ошибка при компиляции
Information:javac 1.8.0_121 was used to compile java sources
Information:23.04.2017 4:43 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1m 50s 896ms
Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module '2.JavaCore'
В фреймворках ни чего такого не отмечено.
[image: В фреймворках ни чего такого не отмечено]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идем по номерам на картинке и удаляем строку с Groovy для примера выделил scala.Только от куда они там я не знаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]